# VBA Formula R1C1 Code

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to put the formula in a range using the code below,  but it is throwing  error. Can someone  help?

```
shtRpt. Range("rng"). FormulaR1C1 = " =OFFSET(INDIRECT(" Sheet1! A1"), Match(RC[30],INDIRECT("Sheet1!A:A),0)-1,8)"
```

Its getting highlighted in red.  I have used R1C1 before  and have not come across such a problem.  Please help?!

Comment: you have to escape your double quotes inside quotes

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: `""` (two double quotes) escapes the double quotes.

Comment: you're also mixing `A1` and `R1C1` referencing. Use one not both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't escaped your double quotes. Something like:

```
shtRpt. Range("rng"). FormulaR1C1 = " =OFFSET(INDIRECT("" Sheet1! A1""), Match(RC[30],INDIRECT(""Sheet1!A:A""),0)-1,8)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- Make sure that your formula in Excel works.
- Select the cell with the formula.
- Run the code below.
- Take a look at the immediate window and compare the values with what you have.
- Adjust the values.

---

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.FormulaR1C1
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

In general, looking at your formula, you have one additional space here `" =OFFSET(INDIRECT("` . It should be like this `"=OFFSET(INDIRECT("`